# Query to Return One Row per Person

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a (simplified) table called Answers like

```
Id  Person      Answer      Priority
1   Tom         France      Low       
2   Tom         Germany     High      
3   Fred        England     Low       
4   Amy         Italy       High
```

I would like to write a SQL query that returns one row per person indicating their highest-priority Answer.  My thought was to use a self-join

```
SELECT *
FROM Answers aLow
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers aHigh 
    ON aLow.Person = aHigh.Person 
       AND aLow.Priority = 'Low' 
       AND aHigh.Priority = 'High'
```

and then examining in code which Priority columns are non-null, but that returns an extra row for Tom

```
Id  Person      Answer      Priority    Id      Person  Answer  Priority
1   Tom         France      Low         2       Tom     Germany High      
2   Tom         Germany     High        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   Fred        England     Low         NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   Amy         Italy       High        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Using this approach the desired output would be

```
Id  Person      Answer      Priority    Id      Person  Answer  Priority
1   Tom         France      Low         2       Tom     Germany High      
3   Fred        England     Low         NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   Amy         Italy       High        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I'm sure I must be missing something simple, but cannot put my finger on it.

What am I missing?  Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: Use DISTINCT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
with priorityRank as
(
  select *
    , priorityRank = row_number() over (partition by Person
        order by case Priority when 'High' then 1 when 'Low' then 2 end
          , Id)
  from
  Answers
)
select Id
  , Person
  , Answer
  , Priority
from priorityRank
where priorityRank = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26712/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression with the `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT [id], 
                [person], 
                [answer], 
                [priority], 
                RN = Row_number() 
                       OVER ( 
                         partition BY person 
                         ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority = 'High' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
                       ASC) 
         FROM   dbo.answers) 
SELECT [id], 
       [person], 
       [answer], 
       [priority] 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9576c/2)

```
ID  PERSON  ANSWER   PRIORITY
4   Amy     Italy    High
3   Fred    England  Low
2   Tom     Germany  High
```

[**Ranking Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you  tried to use DISTINCT like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, Person,Answer, Priority
FROM Answers aLow
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers aHigh 
ON aLow.Person = aHigh.Person 
   AND aLow.Priority = 'Low' 
   AND aHigh.Priority = 'High'
```

Comment: That returns extra, undesired rows.  Also, it does not execute because the column names are ambiguous (I substituted * to test).

Comment: That's why i am explicit on columns so that it will not be ambiguous thus putting an asterisk instead of it will make it ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding you correctly you should get a desired result from

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE Priority = 'Low') aLow
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE Priority = 'High') aHigh 
    ON aLow.Person = aHigh.Person
```

Comment: No, that only returns two rows where the left-hand priority is 'Low'.  Additionally the join side must be specified in SQL Server.  I assume you meant `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Actually I meant full join - sorry, corrected. I did not realize you can have more than one high or low entry per person.